# Laravel - Groupby and merge the other column

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, collections, eloquent

[image]

I have a collection like that, when i perform `groupBy('name')`, it return like this one

[image]

my question is how to merge the "id_area" key when i perform `groupBy('name')` ?
the expected result is more like this

```
"name" => "A"
"id_area" => [3, 1]
```

my eloquent code is

```
$x = Kegiatan::orderBy('name')->groupBy('name')->get();

$y = $x->map(function ($group) {
   return ["name" => $group->name, "id_area" => $group->id_area];
});

dd($y);
```

Comment: Post your query builder code

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid done, edited

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `groupBy()` method of your query builder instead just get your data and then use [`groupBy()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-groupby) method of `Illuminate\Support\Collection` class

```
$collection = Kegiatan::orderBy('name')->get();
$grouped = $collection->groupBy('name');
$grouped->toArray();
```

Using `groupBy()` on query builder will group records by database query and using collection's `groupBy()` will group records once data is fetched by query

Comment: @Willy i have no clue why it doesn't work for you but as per docs [groupBy](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-groupby) it should behave like what you need as your expected output

Comment: it's work, but all i need is to merge the id_area into one array